# jQuery Validation Custom Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, validation

I am currently working on a project and having quite a difficult time with this plugin I managed to get it to work without custom errors one problem I ran across was if I have required tags on all elements email doesn't work but when I have it on just the email input it works. When I attempt to run the custom validation I get no errors upon hitting the submit button.

```css
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".form-horizontal").validate( {
    rules: {
      name: "required", social: "required", postal: {
        required: true, postal: true
      }
      ,
      phone: {
        required: true, phone: true
      }
      ,
      email: {
        required: true, email: true
      }
    }
    ,
    messages: {
      radio: "Please select a gender.", option: "Please select a province."
    }
  }
  );
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Lab 5 Part B</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <span class="navbar-brand">Lab5: Form Validation with jQuery Validation Plugin</span>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      </div>
      <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return false;">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Contact Details</legend>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="status"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputSocial" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Social Insurance No:</label>
            <div class="status"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="social" class="form-control" id="inputSocial" name="inputSocial" placeholder="(9 digits)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputBirth" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Date of Birth:</label>
            <div class="status"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="birth" class="form-control" id="inputBirth" name="inputBirth" placeholder="(YYYY-MM-DD)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Gender:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <div class="radio">
                <div class="status"></div>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="optionsGender" id="optionGenderMale" value="optionGenderMale">Male
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="optionsGender" id="optionGenderFemale" value="optionGenderFemale">Female
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Province:</label>
            <div class="status"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <select class="form-control" name="selectProvince" id="selectProvince">
                <option value="">Select One</option>
                <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
                <option value="NL">Newfoundland & Labrador</option>
                <option value="NS">Novia Scotia</option>
                <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
                <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
                <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
                <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
                <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
                <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPostal" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Postal Code:</label>
            <div class="status"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="postal" class="form-control" id="inputPostal" name="inputPostal" placeholder="(Ex: L8S5CR)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPhone" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Telephone Number:</label>
            <div class="status"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" input="inputPhone" placeholder="(Ex: 905-321-4587)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail:" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="status"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" input="inputEmail">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
              <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; Jamie Steele 2016</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/obLsd65q/1/ - Your input names and named used in the rules are not matching, you have `name="inputName"` in the element but in `rules` you are using `name`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/obLsd65q/2/

Comment: Thank-you I didn't realize the name parameter was used to set validation I  though it was the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your validation rules, you need to use the input element's name, but in your case that is not matching

You have `name="inputName"` in the element but in rules you are using `name`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-horizontal").validate({
    rules: {
      name: "required",
      social: "required",
      postal: {
        required: true,
        postal: true
      },
      phone: {
        required: true,
        phone: true
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      radio: "Please select a gender.",
      option: "Please select a province."
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css">


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <span class="navbar-brand">Lab5: Form Validation with jQuery Validation Plugin</span>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return false;">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Details</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
          <div class="status"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputSocial" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Social Insurance No:</label>
          <div class="status"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="social" class="form-control" id="inputSocial" name="social" placeholder="(9 digits)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputBirth" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Date of Birth:</label>
          <div class="status"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="birth" class="form-control" id="inputBirth" name="inputBirth" placeholder="(YYYY-MM-DD)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Gender:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div class="radio">
              <div class="status"></div>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optionsGender" id="optionGenderMale" value="optionGenderMale">Male
              </label>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optionsGender" id="optionGenderFemale" value="optionGenderFemale">Female
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Province:</label>
          <div class="status"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="selectProvince" id="selectProvince">
              <option value="">Select One</option>
              <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
              <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
              <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
              <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
              <option value="NL">Newfoundland & Labrador</option>
              <option value="NS">Novia Scotia</option>
              <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
              <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
              <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
              <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
              <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
              <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
              <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputPostal" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Postal Code:</label>
          <div class="status"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="postal" class="form-control" id="inputPostal" name="postal" placeholder="(Ex: L8S5CR)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputPhone" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Telephone Number:</label>
          <div class="status"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" name="phone" placeholder="(Ex: 905-321-4587)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail:" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
          <div class="status"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Jamie Steele 2016</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```